# Get layer image data

Tags: konvajs

Is there any way to get a layer image data, like the one that custom filters receive as a param? Yes, I know I can use getImageData and get it, but I was having a problems with it. In draggable canvases, it only captures visible part of the layer. Maybe I can create new canvas, then place a layer there and get image data? But I was wondering if there is any way to do it that is already built into konva?

Comment: Do you want to have a getImageData of the area bigger than canvas?

Comment: Yes, that is also a option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get image data of layer's canvas you can do this:

```
const ctx = layer.getContext();
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
```

If your stage is too small and you need bigger image data, you have to export the layer into a bigger canvas and then get its image data:

```
const canvas = layer.toCanvas({ x: 0, y: 0, width, height});
const imageData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Thanks! This second option is exactly what I needed.